# CreateNewOnMetadataUpdateAttribute does not exists in the namespace after Visual Studio update

Tags: visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-8.0

After updating my Visual Studio to get .Net8, our older Core 2.1 project is getting an error that I can't explain. In the views it is starting to complain about the following:

CS0234  The type or namespace name 'CreateNewOnMetadataUpdateAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Me and a coworker (different machine, same project) experience the same thing after this VS update. We changed nothing in the projects, code or packages. Sometimes it still builds with the error and sometimes it won't build at all.

The error is shown at the top of the views where the @usings and @model are: [image: error in the view]

I don't see others on the internet having this issue. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: You could try posting Feedback using the tooling that is built into VS, but I'm afraid the response will be that .NET Core 2.1 is very much out of support. I can imagine they don't do very extensive testing (or any testing at all) of new VS releases with out-of-support .NET versions. Perhaps the solution is to (re)install the older VS version with which it still worked. Or perhaps it's time to bite the bullet and upgrade it, which is not a bad idea for lots of security and performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah and we are almost there converting it. but we have some older client solutions that we need to support and takes longer to convert. I just don't understand why it is sometimes building and sometimes it wont. Like some project will build even when it gives the error and some project VS refuses to build at all.

Comment: @E.Peter Can you tell more about why you can't upgrade to core 3.1 at least? We have project https://github.com/theraot/Theraot that backports modern C#/.NET goodies to previous tfms (back to .NET Framework 2.0), and thinking about dropping support for netcore1.0 - 3.0 as it is relatively straight forward upgrade path and I was assuming no one is using it today.